# Error handling using integers as input

Tags: python, integer

Ive set up this program that checks the mark out of 100 for a test.  If the user inputs less than 60 it should say fail if more than 59, pass.

```
mark = int(input("Please enter the exam mark out of 100 "))
if mark < 60:
    print("\nFail")
elif mark < 101:
    print("\nPass")
else:
    print("\nThe mark is out of range")
```

how do i get the program not to have errors if the user does not input the Integer.

Please help, is there a quick solution that 14 year olds would understand?

Comment: If you're using python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Then follow one of the answers below.

Comment: `If the user inputs less than 60 it should say fail if more than 59, pass.` So what is the passing score? 59.5? :)

Answer (score 6):

Save the input in a variable and convert to an integer separately:

```
import sys

i = input("Please enter the exam mark out of 100 ")
try:
    mark = int(i)
except ValueError:
    print('\nYou did not enter a valid integer')
    sys.exit(0)
if mark < 60:
    print("\nFail")
elif mark < 101:
    print("\nPass")
else:
    print("\nThe mark is out of range")
```

If it fails (i.e., you get a `ValueError`) then print a message and exit. You can explain (to a 14-year old) that `int()` needs a valid integer as input and it will raise a `ValueError` otherwise. That makes sense because only strings that contain an integer can be converted by `int()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
   mark = int(input("Please enter the exam mark out of 100 "))
except ValueError:
   print("\nPlease only use integers")
```

Comment: "Check its type" -- It will **always be a string**, (which is why `int` is needed).