# Am I using a Python loop wrongly or am I just missing something?

Tags: python

I am currently a beginner in Python. This is my problem: First, the program asks that you input a number.

For example, if I put 1, I get 1 out. If i put 2, i get 12 out. If I put 3, I get 123. If I put 4, I get 1234. That is the gist of this set of problem. However, I developed a mathematical equation that works if I put it through a loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': # ignore this part

    n = int(input())
    s = 1
    while s > n:
        z = s*10**(n-s)
        s += 1
        answer = z
        if s == n:
            print(z)
```

When I tried to run this code, I got nothing, even though I added print at the end. What is it that I am doing wrong here? For anyone answering the problem, introduce any concepts that you know that may help me; I want to learn it.

Please enlighten me. Don't exactly give me the answer....but try to lead me in the right direction. If I made a mistake in the code (which I am 100% sure I did), please explain to me what's wrong.

Comment: With any positive input you will never enter the loop, since the condition is not met.

Comment: for  input =11 output will be `1234567891011` ?

Comment: @prashantrana  that is correct

Comment: your loop condition is always fail. for negative integers ,your code will work but for positive it never enter into loop condition. update the loop condition `while s<n`

Answer (score 1):

It's because your while loop condition is backwards. It never enters the loop because s is not bigger than n. It should be `while s < n`

Comment: Wow...I am quite foolish. Thank you for your feedback slayer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

Using string

```
a = int(input())

# taking the input from the user
res=''
# using empty string easy to append 
for i in range(1,a+1):
     # taking the range from 1 (as user haven't said he want 0, go up to 
     # a+1 number (because range function work inclusively and  will iterate over 
     # a-1 number, but we also need a in final output ))
     res+=str(i)
     # ^ appending the value of I to the string variable so for watch iteration 
     # number come append to it.
     # Example :  1-> 12-> 123-> 1234-> 12345-> 123456-> 1234567-> 12345678-> 123456789
     # so after each iteration number added to it ,in example i have taken a=9

sol = int(res) #converting the res value(string) to int value (as we desire)

print(sol)
```

In one line, the solution is

```
a=int(input())
res=int(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1,a+1)]))
```

Comment: you cannot use strings in this problem

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work for numbers 10 and bigger.

Comment: @Kid_Vic see the updated one. it is working for all numbers

Comment: Spoonfeeding someone a solution doesn't help them learn what they did wrong. Address *why* the original code was wrong, don't just provide an alternative that doesn't explain *why* the alternative is more correct. See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on [meta].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not spoonfeeding, he point out that my previous solution were wrong for  certin case. so i imporved my solution for that

Comment: I wasn't referring to the comments but the answer itself -- it shows "the solution", but doesn't explain anything about *why* this code is more correct than what the OP started with, or how they should approach a problem to end with this (indeed, more correct) solution.

Comment: because i want to help him. and thanks for pointing out the how to answer hommework questions

Comment: @prashantrana.....I think this is the same one as I tried before. Explain to me the logic behind all of these code, mainly the "for" loop you got there. Before I even implement code....I want to know what it is first.

Comment: In it I have taken a empty string and using for loop I am appending (adding)the integer with the string

Comment: @halfer will try to give solution with more explanation from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop using `range()` as in

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
```

where `n` is the input so that the numbers from `1` till `n` can be obtained.

Now use a `print()` to print the value of `i` during each iteration.

`print()` by default will add a newline at the end. To avoid this, use `end` argument like

```
print(var, end='')
```

---

Once you are familiar with this, you can also use [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/5375464) and `join()` to get the output with a single statement like

```
print( ''.join([str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]) )
```

---

Take the input as you've done using `input()` and `int()` although you might want to include exception handling in case the input is not an integer.

See [Error handling using integers as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432913/error-handling-using-integers-as-input).

Comment: What does 'var' mean in this case?

Comment: @Kid_Vic The variable you need to print. So, if in your loop your variable is `i`, replace `var` with `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
n = int(input('Please enter an integer'))
s = 1
do:
    print(s)
    s+=1
while s == n
```

this works.
(Simple and Short)